# Why does one apk got different signatures in jni between emulator and real device?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, signature

I try to print signatures in jni, but the same apk got different values between emulator and real device.
  Does any one knows why this happens?

Emulator Pixel 2:

```
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, [
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 30
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ffffff82
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ffffffdd
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 30
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ffffff82
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 46
2019-07-16 22:38:10.725 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 2
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 30
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, d
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 6
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 9
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 2a
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ffffff86
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 48
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ffffff86
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, fffffff7
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, d
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 5
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 5
2019-07-16 22:38:10.726 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ]
2019-07-16 22:38:10.727 2620-4374/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::checkSignature, appSignature [0x119], [.2.C35(B)649+0,C64*25D1060/7-566]
```

Real Device Huawei:

```
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, [
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 30
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 82
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, dd
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 30
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 82
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 46
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 2
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 30
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, d
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 6
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 9
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 2a
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 86
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 48
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 86
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, f7
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, d
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 1
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 5
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, 5
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, ]
2019-07-16 14:36:44.245 13046-13402/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::checkSignature, appSignature [0x115], [E2EC358B9649B0CC64A25D1060F7D566]
```

java:

```
jstring loadSignature(JNIEnv *env, jobject context) {
//    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::loadSignature");

    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(context);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getPackageManager",
                                     "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");

    jobject pm = env->CallObjectMethod(context, mid);

    mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring packageName = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(context, mid);

    cls = env->GetObjectClass(pm);
    mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getPackageInfo",
                           "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");
    jobject packageInfo = env->CallObjectMethod(pm, mid, packageName, 0x40); //GET_SIGNATURES = 64;
    cls = env->GetObjectClass(packageInfo);
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "signatures", "[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
    jobjectArray signatures = (jobjectArray) env->GetObjectField(packageInfo, fid);
    jobject signature = env->GetObjectArrayElement(signatures, 0);

    cls = env->GetObjectClass(signature);
    mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "toByteArray", "()[B");
    jbyteArray signatureByteArray = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(signature, mid);

    env -> DeleteLocalRef(cls);
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(pm);
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(packageName);
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(packageInfo);
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(signatures);
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(signature);

    {
        // debug signature
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::loadSignature, [");
        jboolean isCopy;
        jbyte *bytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(signatureByteArray, &isCopy);
        char *chars = (char *) bytes;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); i++) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::loadSignature, %x", chars[i]);
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::loadSignature, ]");
    }


    return jbyteArrayToMd5(env, signatureByteArray);
}


jboolean checkSignature(JNIEnv *env, jobject context) {
//    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::checkSignature");

    jstring appSignature = loadSignature(env, context);
    const char *charAppSignature = env->GetStringUTFChars(appSignature, 0);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::checkSignature, %4d, [%s]", strlen(charAppSignature), charAppSignature);
...
```

Update:

```
    2019-07-17 01:23:18.633 11560-13925/my.package.name I/jnitest.cpp: JNI::loadSignature, signaturesSize=1

    jsize signaturesSize = env->GetArrayLength(signatures);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::loadSignature, signaturesSize=%d", signaturesSize);
```

Update:

```
jstring jbyteArrayToMd5(JNIEnv *env, jbyteArray source) {
    //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::jbyteArrayToMd5");

    jclass classMessageDigest = env->FindClass("java/security/MessageDigest");
    jmethodID midGetInstance = env->GetStaticMethodID(classMessageDigest, "getInstance",
                                                      "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/security/MessageDigest;");
    // MessageDigest object
    jobject objMessageDigest = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(classMessageDigest, midGetInstance,
                                                           env->NewStringUTF("md5"));

    jmethodID midUpdate = env->GetMethodID(classMessageDigest, "update", "([B)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(objMessageDigest, midUpdate, source);

    jmethodID midDigest = env->GetMethodID(classMessageDigest, "digest", "()[B");
    jbyteArray objArraySign = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(objMessageDigest, midDigest);

    jsize intArrayLength = env->GetArrayLength(objArraySign);
    jbyte *byte_array_elements = env->GetByteArrayElements(objArraySign, NULL);
    size_t length = (size_t) intArrayLength * 2 + 1;
    char *char_result = (char *) malloc(length);
    memset(char_result, 0, length);

    ByteToHexStr((const char *) byte_array_elements, char_result, intArrayLength);
    *(char_result + intArrayLength * 2) = '\0';

    jstring stringResult = env->NewStringUTF(char_result);
    // release
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(objArraySign, byte_array_elements, JNI_ABORT);
    free(char_result);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(classMessageDigest);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(objMessageDigest);

    return stringResult;
}
```

UPDATE 2nd:

```
void ByteToHexStr(const char *source, char *dest, int sourceLen) {
    //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "JNI::ByteToHexStr");

    short i;
    char highByte, lowByte;

    for (i = 0; i < sourceLen; i++) {
        highByte = source[i] >> 4;
        lowByte = source[i] & 0x0f;
        highByte += 0x30;

        if (highByte > 0x39) {
            dest[i * 2] = highByte + 0x07;
        } else {
            dest[i * 2] = highByte;
        }

        lowByte += 0x30;
        if (lowByte > 0x39) {
            dest[i * 2 + 1] = lowByte + 0x07;
        } else {
            dest[i * 2 + 1] = lowByte;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `strlen` will stop at the first zero byte in your signature. Use `env->GetArrayLength(signatureByteArray)` instead.

Comment: Also, did you check if there are multiple signatures in the `signatures` array?

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#signatures) supports this: "Note: Signature ordering is not guaranteed to be stable which means that a package signed with certificates A and B is equivalent to being signed with certificates B and A. This means that in case multiple signatures are reported you cannot assume the one at the first position to be the same across updates."

Comment: Thx :-) 1st, I will changed to env->GetArrayLength(signatureByteArray) instead. 2nd, However I only have certificates A, no certificates B. 3rd, I notice that the tail number of each signatureByteArray is equal, but in emulator ffffff is added to same tail  number.

Comment: @Botje, I checked multiple signatures and size in update above, it is always 1.

Comment: I would not read too much into the log output. If you use `%hhx` instead printf will treat its input as a char instead of a sign-extended int.

Comment: @Botje, Yes, you are right, after replace with %hhx, both print the same arrays. But after env->GetStringUTFChars, they are still different: [.2.C35(B)649+0,C64*25D1060/7-566] in emulator and [E2EC358B9649B0CC64A25D1060F7D566] in real device.

Comment: That looks like the output of "jbyteArrayToMd5", which you did not post.

Comment: @Botje, I updated jbyteArrayToMd5, thx.

Comment: ... And bytetohexstr?

Comment: @Botje, I updated and appreciate your long-term support。

Answer (score 1):

To quote Adam Savage: There's your problem!
Your `ByteToHexStr` takes in signed chars and performs bit manipulations on them.
The behavior of these operations is [implementation defined](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=87152374#content/view/87152374).

I noticed this earlier when *parts* of your MD5string were corrupted, but not others. Now that you posted the implementation of `ByteToHexStr`, I know why.
The right-shift operator you use to get the high nybble preserves the sign of the input.
For the byte `0xCC`, that means that the high byte goes through the following steps:

- `-0xC` after right shift
- `0x2C` after adding `0x30`, which is ASCII comma (`,`)

See for yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    signed char c = 0xCC;
    signed char low = c & 0xf;
    signed char high = c >> 4;
    printf("low: %d high: %d\n", low+0x30, high+0x30);
}
```

Explicitly using `unsigned char` instead of (`signed`) `char` should fix this issue and make both platforms behave the same.